# Typescript Compile Error using a tuple declaration

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

[image]

1. Why does line 62 have an error?
2. Why does the panel below says "no errors"?
3. Why are there three repeated errors about a ',' expected?

Comment: Not sure, but FYI it works fine in the playground: http://goo.gl/s4t0xE

Comment: Maybe just a bug in atom/typescript. I found that by adding and deleting blank lines the error messages change, including disappear...

Comment: Its a bug in linter https://github.com/AtomLinter/Linter/issues/707#issuecomment-119084165 that has been fixed. Expect a release soon (I am not a collab on that project so can't do a release myself)

Answer (score 1):

## Update : This error is fixed

Thanks to the effort of https://stackoverflow.com/users/2652018/steel-brain

## For history:

Basically the error panel is telling the truth, there are no errors.

The error you are seeing (inline and in the bottom) are reported by the linter. This was a bug which was reported : https://github.com/AtomLinter/Linter/issues/707 and has been fixed since then. Hopefully they will do a release soon https://github.com/AtomLinter/Linter/issues/707#issuecomment-119084165

Comment: To future visitors: The release was published 7 hours after this was posted.

Comment: Updated answer ;) You are going to go far kid. Best of luck!